# How should this site's general chat room be named?

Tags: discussion, chat

Unable to find the general chat room for this new site and thus assuming it does not yet exist:

How should our main chat room be named? It is custom to use a clever play of words on the topic of the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're thinking about the name for the chat, basically, you want to take several things into account.

1. It wants to be short.  For instance, we probably don't want your chat to be named something like: *The Room in Which we Discuss Various Matters Concerning the StackExchange site entitled "The Internet of Things" and other...*
2. It wants to be distinctive.  In other words, we probably don't want it to be called *General Room for IoT*.
3. It doesn't want to look like the main site's title.  It puts a bit of confusion when you look at tab titles if you have a dozen tabs open.  In other words, we probably don't want it called something like: *IoT chat* or the suchlike.

**In view of those things...**

How about *Chat of Things*?

It is simple, and obviously belongs to our site.  It is distinctive, and a glance suffices to find it among multiple tabs. It is a play on words, which could give it a witty feeling.  Let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

The internet of things is made out of connections between machines. The chat is a place where all people on the site are welcome to "connect" with each other, making it a "hub" for social interaction.

I would call it "**The Router**," or "**The Central Node**."

I also quite like the current name: "**Things**" As it is a play of words on internet of things, but, without the blunt in your face play on words with "Chat of things."

Answer (score 2):

#### Connected People

The Internet of things are also referred to as "connected devices", so room with "connected people" using "connected devices" would be great.

Answer (score 0):

How about?

- The IoT Zone

It's simple and it relates to the topic of the site.

Answer (score -1):

#### IoT

Simple and short. Abbreviation of *Internet of Things*.

Answer (score -2):

#### The Internetworking

The IoT is the internetworking of physical devices<sup>[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things)</sup>.

Answer (score -2):

#### The Smart Room

The Internet of things are also referred to as "connected devices" and "smart devices", so why not to have The Smart Room.

Answer (score -4):

How about

- Netter Chat
- The Packets of Computers

Comment: that means *nice chat* in German ;)

Comment: @Helmar sorry, is that bad?

Comment: Not necessarily, just wanted to make it known.

Answer (score -5):

Or

- Let's Chat IoT

Also simple and relates to the topic of the site.